# How to initialize list in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, hcl

I want to create a variable that has a single value, a list of elements. So I did:

```
variable "cipher_suites" = {
     type    = list(string)
     default =  [
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
     ]
}
```

and this

```
   variable "cipher_suites" {
         type    = "list"
         default =  [
          "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
          "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
         ]
    }
```

but then I get a lot of errors like this regarding my declaration and initialization:

```
This character is not used
2019-10-09T06:41:12.2239556Z within the language.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the rigth way, and it works for me.

```
 variable "cipher_suites" {
         type    = list(string)
         default =  [
          "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
          "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
         ]
    }
```

Hope it help, if this don't work for you, probably is another error, maybe some imports or something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't understand, after I tried your syntax(it works) and then modifying to the 2nd form presented by me in the question it works too. Does HCL blacklists some whitespace characters?

Comment: I think so, but the problem with the 1st was the equal assigment.